# Bulk Device Subscription in PubNub

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, pubnub

I'm looking for a method to send APNS/GCM push messages to many thousands of users.  The pool of users is determined at run-time, and can change depending on the message being sent.

The current implementation I have is to subscribe each device token one-by-one to a particular channel in a multithreaded fashion, making a huge number of HTTP calls to the REST API.

Is there a better solution, it feels like there must be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [PubNub Mobile Push Gateway](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/data-streams-publish-and-subscribe)

The [PubNub mobile push channel registration API](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/mobile-gateway) is not setup to do bulk registration. It is designed to handle individual devices registering for channels for push notifications. So the only way to register multiple (many thousand) devices is to loop through all the device tokens to register each one by one.

Comment: By the way, this is something that we are considering to add to the API. It would likely allow you to register up to a limited number of devices with one call (for example, 100 at a time, which would at least reduce the number of calls).